# Clonar repositório privado passando senha como parâmetro

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu

Eu possuo um script no meu servidor de produção que automatiza todo o processo de checagem de novos commits, gerando o build e publicando as novas alterações.

Ele funciona perfeitamente com repositórios abertos, rodando o código:

```
git clone -b meu-branch http://minha-url-repo.git
```

O problema é que em repositórios privados, ao rodar o comando acima o terminal sempre retorna um *prompt* pedindo a senha de acesso ao repositório. O que faz com que o processo deixe de ser automatizado (já que alguém precisaria escrever a senha).

Existe alguma forma de passar o usuário e a senha junto do comando de `git clone` de forma que este comando rodasse 100% automatizado?

<sup>**Obs.: O usuário e senha utilizados seriam *readonly* por questões de segurança, e o servidor é restrito.**</sup>

Answer (score 5):

Em um servidor interno, você pode tentar usar o seguinte formato:

```
git clone -b meu-branch http://usuario:senha@minha-url-repo.git
```

Porém, tenha em mente que essa URL com o usuário e a senha potencialmente vai aparecer em logs de acesso, portanto pessoas não autorizadas, ainda que da própria empresa, podem ter acesso à credencial.

Se não funcionar, você deve verificar [quais tipos de protocolo](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols) seu servidor Git suporta, pois existem outras alternativas.

Independente do resultado, uma abordagem mais segura e mais apropriada para esse tipo de situação seria usar o protocolo SSH com autenticação baseada via chave pública. Além de mais seguro, evita qualquer tipo de credencial fixa no seu código.